# Constructor breaks app without class instantiation

Tags: php, class, constructor

```
class KnivesModel {

private $db;

public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass){
    try{
        $this->$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        var_dump($e);
    };

}; // __construct

}
```

This code breaks my app. I'm not even instantiating this class yet. All I do is include this class in my index.php and the "app" blows up with 500 error. What's the problem?

Comment: Enable `error_reporting=` or at least look into the webservers `error.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no `;` at the end of the `try catch` and the `__construct` function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` at the end of the constructor declaration and `try/catch` block:

```
class KnivesModel {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass){
        try{
            $this->$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            var_dump($e);
        } // <<< Right here

    } // <<< Right here

}
```